# how to call useMutation hook from a function?

Tags: reactjs

I have this functional React component:

```
// CreateNotification.tsx

import {useMutation} from '@apollo/client';
import resolvers from '../resolvers';

const createNotification = (notification) => {
  const [createNotification] = useMutation(resolvers.mutations.CreateNotification);

  createNotification({
    variables: {
      movie_id: notification.movie.id,
      actor_id: notification.user.id,
      message:
        `${notification.user.user_name} has added ${notification.movie.original_title} to their watchlist.`,
    },
  });
};

export default createNotification;
```

I call the `createNotification` component in a function and pass in some variables after a other `useMutation` hook has been called:

```
// AddMovie.tsx

  const addMovie = async (movie: IMovie) => {
    await addUserToMovie({
      variables: {...movie, tmdb_id: movie.id},
      update: (cache, {data}) => {
        cache.modify({
          fields: {
            moviesFromUser: () => {
              return [...data.addUserToMovie];
            },
          },
        });
      },
    }).then( async () => {
      createNotification({movie: movie, user: currentUserVar()});
    });
  };
```

When I run the code I get the (obvious) error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Because I call the `createNotification` hook in the `addMovie` function.

If I move the `createNotification` to the top of the component:

```
// AddMovie.tsx

const AddMovieToWatchList = ({movie}: {movie: IMovie}) => {
  createNotification({movie: movie, user: currentUserVar()});
  const [addUserToMovie] = useMutation(resolvers.mutations.AddUserToMovie);

  const addMovie = async (movie: IMovie) => {
    await addUserToMovie({
      variables: {...movie, tmdb_id: movie.id},
      update: (cache, {data}) => {
        cache.modify({
          fields: {
            moviesFromUser: () => {
              return [...data.addUserToMovie];
            },
          },
        });
      },
    });
  };
}
```

The code works fine, except that the hook is now called every time the `AddMovie` component is rendered instead of when the `addMovie` function is called from the click:

```
  return (
    <a className={classes.addMovie} onClick={() => addMovie(movie)}>
    Add movie to your watchlist
    </a>
  );
```

Comment: The error is described well. In react all hooks can be executed only within functional components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
// createNotification.tsx

import {useMutation} from '@apollo/client';
import resolvers from '../resolvers';

export const createNotification = () => {
  const [createNotification, {data, loading, error}] = useMutation(resolvers.mutations.CreateNotification);

  const handleCreateNotification = async (notification) => {
    createNotification({
      variables: {
        movie_id: notification.movie.id,
        actor_id: notification.user.id,
        message:
          `${notification.user.user_name} has added ${notification.movie.original_title} to their watchlist.`,
      },
    });

    console.log(data, loading, error);
  };

  return {
    createNotification: handleCreateNotification,
  };
};
```

If I'm correct then this returns a reference (`createNotification`) to the function `handleCreateNotification`

Then in the component I want to use the `createNotification` helper I import it:

```
// AddMovie.tsx

import {createNotification} from '../../../../helpers/createNotification';

const AddMovieToWatchList = ({movie}: {movie: IMovie}) => {
  const x = createNotification();

  const addMovie = async (movie: IMovie) => {
      await addUserToMovie({
        variables: {...movie, tmdb_id: movie.id},
        update: (cache, {data}) => {
          cache.modify({
            fields: {
              moviesFromUser: () => {
                return [...data.addUserToMovie];
              },
            },
          });
        },
      }).then( async () => {
        x.createNotification({movie: movie, user: currentUserVar()});
      });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You (kind of) answer your own question by showing the error and saying it's obvious. `createNotification` is not a React component, and it is not a custom hook, it is just a function. Thus using a hook inside of it breaks the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

If you want to keep that logic in it's own function, that's fine, just redefine your component like this:

```
const AddMovieToWatchList = ({movie}: {movie: IMovie}) => {
  const [addUserToMovie] = useMutation(resolvers.mutations.AddUserToMovie);
  const [createNotification] = useMutation(resolvers.mutations.CreateNotification);


  const addMovie = async (movie: IMovie) => {
    await addUserToMovie({
      variables: {...movie, tmdb_id: movie.id},
      update: (cache, {data}) => {
        cache.modify({
          fields: {
            moviesFromUser: () => {
              return [...data.addUserToMovie];
            },
          },
        });
      },
    });

    await createNotification({movie: movie, user: currentUserVar()});
  };

  return (
    <a className={classes.addMovie} onClick={() => addMovie(movie)}>
    Add movie to your watchlist
    </a>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't think the issue is that the `createNotification` component isn't a functional React component, but that I can't instantiate it in a function. I want to abstract the `useMutation` hook so I can import the `createNotification` component in several other components

Comment: That is the issue... If you want it abstracted you must turn it into a custom hook. Hooks can only be used in React components and custom hooks.